# Swift - Generate a random path

Tags: swift, random, path, maze

I am trying to create a simple maze, that will be based on a grid, 5x9 (for the iphone 5) The maze will be made with simple white squares(path) and black squares (the walls). How is it possible to generate a code that will make the path totally random, but will always be passable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is too broad, please explain what part of the task you have problems with (maze generation, implementation in Swift, display, ..., all of the above?). Note also that there are *lots* of maze generating algorithms available in the Internet. This one even has Swift code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation.

Comment: I am basically trying to make a never ending scrolling up-down maze in swift. I cant find another solution, as to just make every possible maze path that is possible and implement that into swift, but that is too much work...

Answer (score 1):

Consider an NxN grid of cells, each of which initially has a wall between it and its four neighbouring cells. 
For each cell (x, y), maintain a variable up[x,y] that is true if there is wall separating (x, y) and (x, y + 1). 
Maintain analogous variables left[x, y], down[x,y], and right[x,y] for the corresponding walls.

Note that if there is a wall above (x, y) then up[x,y] = down[x,y+1] = true. Construct the maze by knocking down some of the walls as follows:

1. Start at the lower level cell (1, 1).
2. Find a neighbour at random that you haven't yet been to.
3. If you find one, move there, knocking down the wall. If you don't find one, go back to the previous cell.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you've been to every cell in the grid.

**Source:** http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/

A Swift implementation can be found at:
https://github.com/lucaslouca/swift-mazes

Comment: When answering, a link is great but it would be even more helpful if you took the most important part from it and put it here.